# Why do we need $End(I)=k$ for neutral Tannakian categories?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, representation-theory, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories

I have been reading Milne's book 'Basic Theory of Affine Group Schemes', and in particular the section on Tannaka duality for affine group schemes. The 'final' theorem of this section is displayed below:

[image]

The conditions in 3.13 are given by

1. $\omega(X\otimes Y) = \omega(X) \otimes \omega(Y)$
2. There are natural isomorphisms $a_{X,Y,Z}: (X\otimes Y)\otimes Z \rightarrow X\otimes (Y\otimes Z)$ and $\tau_{X,Y}: X\otimes Y \rightarrow Y\otimes X$ whose images under $\omega$ are the usual associativity and commutativity isomorphisms of the tensor product of vector spaces
3. There is an object $I\in \textbf{C}$ such that $\omega(I) = k$ and isomorphisms $X\otimes I \simeq X \simeq I \otimes X$ whose images are the canonical isomorphisms making $k$ the tensor unit of vector spaces

Because this description of the conditions is a bit lengthily, I also looked into 'Tannakian Categories' by Milne and Deligne, and I found the following theorem:

[image]

Now clearly the condition of being rigid just makes the difference between affine group scheme and affine monoid scheme. But there also is the condition that $\text{End}(I)$ should be the field $k$, and I do not see any counterpart to this in the first exposition. I know that this condition is the same as stating that $I$ should be a simple object, but I do not see any reference to that in the first theorem either.

What am I missing?

Comment: The existence of $\omega$ implies that $(C,\otimes)$ is a tensor category. The $I$ in 3 is an identity object for it, and $End(I)=k$ because $\omega$ is faithful. Any other identity object is (uniquely) isomorphic to $I$.

Comment: That's what I thought too. But one can restate the conditions of the first theorem as '$\textbf{C}$ is a monoidal category and $\omega$ is strong monoidal'. Then we have the same situation as below; so do we conclude that $\text{End}(I)=k$ follows from these conditions also? Then why do we state it at all??

Comment: The condition $End(I)=k$ is important for nonneutral Tannakian categories. Saavedra claimed to prove his results without it, but they fail without it.

Comment: @anon So it is true that $\text{End}(I) = k$ is redundant for the neutral case?